# Geometric interpretation of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}/H$ for these $H$

Tags: abstract-algebra

$\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}/H$ with: ($G=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$)

$H=\{(x,0)|x\in\mathbb{R}\}$
$H=\{(x,y)|y=-x\}$
$H=\{(x,y)|y=2x\}$

This is from a book (Pinter's "A book of abstract algebra") in a chapter before use of the isomorphism theorems (so [Understanding the quotient of infinite groups $\mathbb{R}^2/H$ where $H = \{(a, 0): a\in \mathbb{R}\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525223/understanding-the-quotient-of-infinite-groups-mathbbr2-h-where-h-a) doesn't apply)

The question asks: "In geometric terms describe the elements of G/H" and "in geometric terms describe the operation of G/H"

I'm quite stuck. For example with the first one, $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}/H=\{(x+u,v)|x,u,v\in\mathbb{R}\}$

Which doesn't really help.

There are no answers for this in the back of the book, so I'm not sure what I'm even looking for.

**Addendum**

Slight mistake with the first one, $G/H=\{\{(x+u,v)|x\in\mathbb{R}\}|u,v\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is what it should read, which is quite simply "the set of all horizontal lines"

I will try to proceed (this is my third error) - I would still like to know what I should be spotting regarding the geometric interpretation.

Comment: Your addended interpretation of $\Bbb R^2 / H_1$ seems sound. The two others will also be sets of lines, although they won't be horizontal.

Comment: @Arthur now I've got it right it is a lot easier - having said that I'd still like to accurately describe (in the sense of what the question wants) the operation

Answer (score 1):

An idea: try to find out what two equal elements modulo $\;H\;$  look like, say in the first case:

$$(a,b)+H=(x,y)+H\iff (a-x, b-y)\in H\iff b-y=0\iff b=y$$

and this means every horizontal line $\;y=k\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb R\;\;\text{a constant}\;$ , yields one single element in the quotient.

Or in the second case:

$$(a,b)+H=(x,y)+H\iff (a-x, b-y)\in H\iff b-y=x-a\iff a+b=x+y$$

so that every line of the form $\;y=-x+k\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb R\;\;\text{a constant}\;$ , yields the same element, and etc.

Observe that in both cases above we get lines that are a translation of the one defining $\;H\;$ ...

Answer (score 0):

Geometrical meaning of quotient is "gluing" points which differ by element of $H$. If $H$ is a line, for any point $(x, y)$ you "glue" all points which are lying on line parallel to one described by $H$ and going through (x, y). Therefore an element of quotient space is not a point (x, y), but all points on line described above. And therefore quotient space can be thought as space of all lines parallel to one described in $H$.